# checking the content of a select to change a css property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, detection

I'm making a website where you have several select option that you can use to create sentences.
I would like to be able to detect when the user is changing them to create some specific sentences, like "I", "Am", "Blue" is changing the color to blue.
In fact that's just an option and I'd like to have a list of several action, "I am Big", "I am rotated" and do something different each time, so I tried this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    console.log(phrase);
    if (phrase = "Is big"){
       $(".white").css('font-size', '5em');
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work since the code is not able to reach the function *phrase* (which is somewhere else is the following code).
This code is creating a phrase at the beginning, keeping it and making it evolve when you change the select values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

                    });

                    let phrases = ["I am not. "

                    ];
                    let lettres = /[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00aa-\u00b5\u00ba-\u00c0\u00c1-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6]/gui;

                    tokenize = function(phrase) {
                        let mots = [''];
                        let it = phrase[Symbol.iterator]();
                        for (var c = it.next(); !c.done; ) {

                            for (; !c.done && c.value.match(lettres); c = it.next()) {
                                mots[mots.length-1]+=(c.value);
                            }
                        //console.log(c.value);
                        if (mots[mots.length-1].length != 0 ){
                            mots.push('');
                        }

                        if (c.value == ' ') {
                            for (c = it.next(); !c.done && c.value == " "; c = it.next()) {continue;} continue;
                        } 
                            // console.log(i);
                            
                            console.log(mots);

                            if (!c.value.match(lettres)){
                                mots[mots.length-1]+=(c.value);
                            //console.log(c.value);
                            mots.push('');
                        }
                        c = it.next();
                    }
                    return mots.slice(0, mots.length-1);

                
                }



                $(document).ready(function() {
                    let LARGEUR = $("#container .repeat").clone();
                    let change=function(){
                        $(".width_tmp_option", this.parent).html($('option:selected', this).val());
                        $(this).width($(".width_tmp_select", this.parent).width());
                    }
                    $('#container').on("change",".un",change);


                    let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(phrases.length));
                    let mots = tokenize(phrases[idx]);

                    for( var i = 0 ; i < mots.length-1; i++){
                        $('#container .repeat:last-child').after(LARGEUR.clone());}
                        var i = 0;
                        console.log(mots.length);
                        $('#container .repeat').each(function(){
                            $('.un', this).val(mots[i]).each(change);
                            i++;

                        });

  

        });
```

```css
@font-face {
        font-family: "Lexicon";
        src: url("fontes/Lexicon.woff") format("woff");
    }


    body {
        width: 70vw;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: normal;
        font-family:'Lexicon';
        overflow: hidden;


    }

    .un{
        width: 2rem;
        margin: 0.2rem;
        font-family: 'Lexicon';
    } 

    option {
        background-color: none;
        font-family: 'Lexicon';
    }

    option:hover {
        background-color: green;

    }

    ::selection {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .width_tmp_select{
        background-color: none;

    }


    .width_tmp_select{
        display : none;
        font-size: 2.5rem; 
        font-family: 'Lexicon';
    } 

    .un{
        font-size: 2.5rem; 

    } 

    #p1{
        font-size: 2rem;
        border: none;
    } 

    select {

    }

    /* For IE10 */
    select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;

    }

    .repeat {
        display: inline-block;


    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body class="white">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="repeat">
      <select name="mots" class="un">
        <option value=""> </option>
        <option value=".">.</option>
        <option value="I">I</option>
        <option value="am">am</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="not">not</option>
        <option value="is">is</option>
        <option value="big">big</option>
        <option value="!">!</option>
      </select>
      <select class="width_tmp_select">
        <option class="width_tmp_option"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check out the console. It kinda shows you what is wrong in your snippet.

Comment: could you please, enlight me, since I think I know what it means, I don't know how to solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `phrase = "Is big"` you set the variable `parse` to be equal `"Is big"` if you want to check if it's equal use `phrase === "Is big"`.

full cose:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
                        console.log(phrase);
                        if (phrase === "Is big"){
                        $(".white").css('font-size', '5em');
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: alright, thanks I fixed it. When I try to check, the code is telling me that phrase is not defined. Here is a JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ys0jkezq/

Comment: where you define it?

Comment: at line 12, I have a tokensize that is setting a first phrase that the user is invited to play with.

Comment: at line 12 you define a function which receive `phrase` as a parameter. it's a local variabe

Comment: If you trying to get the concated values of the selects you can use `let phrase = $('.un').get().reduce((a,b) => a+' '+b.value, '').trim();`

Comment: thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed to make it work.
you are fantastic!

Comment: One last question,
Now this is working, I would like to detect if "Is big" is somewhere in my phrase variable.
Do you have any idea on how to achieve that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `phrase.includes('Is big')`

Comment: I am sorry, i'm new to this...
How do I have to use it?
With a if?
Like :if (phrase.includes('text'){}); ?